# How can i make a service in node js that will perform task for different users in different specific time that stored in Database

Tags: node.js, service, node-cron

I want to make a service in nodejs that will perform some task for different users in different time. I have some idea about node-corn. But it do task in fixed time for one user i guess. Can i write any servic for multiple user in different time

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule("* 1 * * * *", function() {
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log("Running Cron Job every one Hours");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a job queue table/collection with a task activation field, You can use MongoDB or Mysql for that.
2. Push items to it with appropriate props
3. Develop a job scheduler (Can be a cron enabled AWS Lambda function) polls this table for new tasks & execute a task based on the activation time.